# Intellij Idea Android development R.main

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have problem with IntelliJ recognising R.menu. When I start new project I code following code

```
package com.example.HelloWorld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Color;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        text.setText("Alex ");
        setContentView(text);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

When I do the code in eclipse it works fine but in IntelliJ it says it `cannot resolve symbol 'menu'`

Anyone has a solution?

By the way I'm new to IntelliJ environment

Comment: When you copied your project to IntelliJ, did you also move the main.xml menu layout file from /res/menu?  In Eclipse, the file usually auto-generates as main_menu.xml, but it's also possible that you might have renamed it.

Comment: Yeah I just looked through the folders and that was the problem thanks. It's me being stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I had xml file missing with menu folder in resources